# Intermittent errors: java.io.IOException: Failed to advance reader of source: BigtableSource{config=BigtableConfig{projectId=

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I've been getting intermittent errors like the following trying to connect to bigtable to read about ~7millions row of data using Dataflow:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to advance reader of source: 
BigtableSource{config=BigtableConfig{projectId=
```

**-- removed detail information about the configuration since it is sensitive information, but I do have a couple of rowfilters to filter out only column qualifiers I am interested in and another one for a particular column family.**

```
    }
  }
  filters {
    cells_per_column_limit_filter: 1
  }
}

, ranges=[ByteKeyRange{startKey=[some_key_range_start], endKey=[some_key_range_end]}], estimatedSizeBytes=372856848384}
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources$BoundedReaderIterator.advance(WorkerCustomSources.java:606)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation$SynchronizedReaderIterator.advance(ReadOperation.java:399)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:194)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.executeWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:394)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.doWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:363)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:291)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:135)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:115)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:102)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.BigtableRetriesExhaustedException: Exhausted streaming retries.
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResumingStreamingResultScanner.next(ResumingStreamingResultScanner.java:88)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResumingStreamingResultScanner.next(ResumingStreamingResultScanner.java:34)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableDataGrpcClient$7.next(BigtableDataGrpcClient.java:437)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableDataGrpcClient$7.next(BigtableDataGrpcClient.java:418)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigtable.BigtableServiceImpl$BigtableReaderImpl.advance(BigtableServiceImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigtable.BigtableIO$BigtableReader.advance(BigtableIO.java:1203)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources$BoundedReaderIterator.advance(WorkerCustomSources.java:603)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.IOExceptionWithStatus: Error in response stream
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResultQueueEntry$ExceptionResultQueueEntry.getResponseOrThrow(ResultQueueEntry.java:100)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResponseQueueReader.getNextMergedRow(ResponseQueueReader.java:107)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResponseQueueReader.getNextMergedRow(ResponseQueueReader.java:113)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.ResumingStreamingResultScanner.next(ResumingStreamingResultScanner.java:79)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: HTTP/2 error code: INTERNAL_ERROR
Received Rst Stream
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:517)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.async.AbstractRetryingOperation.onError(AbstractRetryingOperation.java:222)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.async.AbstractRetryingOperation.onClose(AbstractRetryingOperation.java:187)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.scanner.RetryingReadRowsOperation.onClose(RetryingReadRowsOperation.java:232)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.ChannelPool$InstrumentedChannel$2.onClose(ChannelPool.java:210)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor$UnAuthResponseListener.onClose(RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor.java:85)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:684)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:403)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:459)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:63)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:546)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:467)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:584)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    ... 3 more
```

I would get one of them from time to time or once every hour at one point then eventually it halted the entire pipeline (it was a batch job reading from bigtable) with the following message

```
A work item was attempted 4 times without success. Each time the worker eventually lost contact with the service. The work item was attempted on:
```

Any help or insights to why this is happening would be appreciated!

Thanks
KT

Comment: There likely isn't enough information present in this post to get a solution to your problem. I'd suggest opening a support ticket, or checking for some common error cases such as overloaded CPU from [Monitoring Instance](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/monitoring-instance) or row hot spotting from [Key Visualizer](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/keyvis-overview)

Answer (score 1):

For runtime performance or connectivity issues like this as noted by Dan, it is probably best to open a support ticket since that will allow you to provide the more sensitive information needed to diagnose your specific issues.

See also:
https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/support/getting-support